# Sharepoint: how to use web services method

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, url, parameters

I need to use the web services available by adding `/_vti_bin/webs.asmx` to your site URL. In particular `GetAllSubWebCollection`.

Sorry if this is a noobish question, I work in a split 2007-front 2010-back environment and do not have access to the server so I have little experience with advanced features.

What do I have to enter into the URL to get this method to work? Am I supposed to create a page to handle the info?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to do to use that method.  Did you have a question about something?  I don't see a question here...

Comment: Im wondering how to actually use the method via the URL, sorry I guess I assumed the title would explain it

Comment: This question just doesn't make any sense. What do you mean "get this method to work"? From what context are you trying to call it?

Comment: I mean execute, and I'm TRYING to use it from the URL. But I don't know if that's right.. What context can I call it from? I just want to know how to use the method to get a site count.. Thanks

Comment: It's important to know what context you are using, because you might not actually need to use the web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Web Reference (not a Service Reference) in Visual Studio. This service is a SOAP service, so you won't be able to just type a url into your browser to call this method. You'll need to send a SOAP message to the service. .NET handles this for you when you add a web reference. If you're using SP 2010, use the Client Object Model instead.

Comment: Thank you for suffering a student. <-- are thank you's allowed?